# Implementing K-d tree with longitude and latitude points

Tags: binary-tree, latitude-longitude, kdtree

I currently have a very long list of points in the world that I need to iterate through, and find the closest point on the world from another point. Basically I have a ton of Point As, and a ton of Point Bs, and all As need to be matched to the closest point B. I first implemented this by just finding the distance between each point A from each point B using the haversine function, but this is obviously very inefficient. From doing some research, a K-d tree seems like the ideal choice here, but I'm not fully sure. I found a python library for a K-d tree implementation, but the issue is the distance between 2 coordinates on the globe isn't the same as using 2 coordinates on a 2d plane. I'd rather not write my own K-d tree implementation, so I was wondering if there was any way to essentially convert each long/lat pair to a point on a 2d plane? And then I could just use those values for my k-d tree?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: *"if there was any way to essentially convert each long/lat pair to a point on a 2d plane?"*: this is what [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) do, but they cannot maintain the distance properties. If all pairwise distances need to be maintained, your pointset cannot be mapped on a plane.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a KdTree to speed up searches, you could try to use a [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html). In the referenced library it defaults to using the `minkowski` metric, but you can use the `haversine` metric too (as part of `BallTree.valid_metrics`).

Using a projection could indeed work as well if you want to keep using the KdTree and the points in your list are limited to a particular area in the world. There are many projected coordinate systems such as [UTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). [This](https://github.com/Turbo87/utm) library may be interesting for this approach.